# best way to reuse dynamic content in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app where I need to reuse the same content.  I created the html content and can append it to the page with no problem, but I need to reuse the same content keeping track of what was selected each time it is displayed.

It goes like this...

A user selects the type of service they want.

From that selection I have a default number of times I need to show the dynamic content.

I load the dynamic content, they make a selection.  That selection will be stored and used later in a calculation.

I then need to reshow the same dynamic content, just changing the text in the label.

The user makes another selection and again I need to store the selected value to be used later.

What would be the best way to do this?  I have looked all over the web for some ideas with no luck.
Thanks

Comment: localStorage maybe? or global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is not reloaded during the “lifecycle” of your data container, you can use a global object. The best would be to attach it to the global `window` object.

```
window.$myElementReference = $(#some-element);
```

If you have several objects that need to be accessed globally, you can use a little class that manages the stored objects for you. It could look like this:

```javascript
window.storageManager =
{
    _shelf : {},

    has : function(key)
    {
        return window.storageManager._shelf[key] ? true : false;
    },

    get : function(key)
    {
        return window.storageManager._shelf[key] || null;
    },

    put : function(key, value)
    {
        window.storageManager._shelf[key] = value;
    }
};
```

You can use it like this:

```javascript
var mySettings =  { foo: 'bar' };
window.storageManager.put('mySettings', mySettings); // stores the mySettings object

// somewhere completely different
var mySettings = window.storageManager.get('mySettings'); // returns mySettings object
```

You can even use this on DOM nodes created by jQuery:

```javascript
var $myElem =  $('#elem');
window.storageManager.put('myElem, $myElem); // stores the mySettings object
var $referenceToMyElem = window.storageManager.get('myElem');
```

Of course, it's not really great coding to toss DOM nodes around in random places of your code base. But for those few cases, the above code should be helpful.

Comment: Sounds great.  Will this work offline with PhoneGap?

Comment: I have 3 dynamic content sections.  I show 1, take selection, show the 2nd, take selection, show 3rd take selection, then repeat.  I am fairly new to javascript, but trying to learn as fast as I can. Do I wrap the window.storage manager in a function? Should I have 3 of the window.storage functions to handle all three of the forms?

Comment: Just put it at the top level of your code and load it once. It's a global “static” object. Then you can store as many things as you like; just use a different `key` each time.

Comment: By the way, if you're still learning, I'd ask you to read a tutorial or a book. Stack Overflow is not well suited for providing the basic understanding of programming languages.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have signed up with Pluralsite.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you have fun working through their tutorials.